# Angular2 handle http post promise in component

Tags: angular, http-post, angular-promise

Fairly new to angular2....

I have created a login service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Request } from '../model/request';
import { ApiResponse } from '../model/apiresponse';
import { UserCredentials } from '../model/user';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'


@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
private request = new Request();
constructor(private http: Http, _router: Router) { }

login(userCredentials:UserCredentials): Promise<ApiResponse> {
    console.log("requesting login")
    this.request.ServiceType = "Connect"
    this.request.SessionId = "sessionlessrequest"
    this.request.Compression = "no"
    this.request.Parameters = userCredentials;
    let jsonrequest = JSON.stringify(this.request)
    return this.http.post("http://localhost/request.php", "data="+ jsonrequest,
        { headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })
    }).toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
}



logout() {

}

}
```

Calling this service from my login component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginService} from '../shared/login.service';
import { UserCredentials } from '../model/user';
import { ApiResponse } from '../model/apiresponse';

@Component({
selector: 'login',
templateUrl: './app/login/login.component.html',
providers: [LoginService, UserCredentials]
})

export class LoginComponent {
public usercredentials = new UserCredentials();
public apiResponse:ApiResponse
constructor(private loginService:LoginService, userCredentials:UserCredentials) {
}
login(): void {
    console.log(this.usercredentials)
    //let apiResponse = this.loginService.login(this.usercredentials)
    this.loginService.login(this.usercredentials).then(apiResponse => this.apiResponse = apiResponse)
    //let response = apiResponse as ApiResponse
    console.log(this.apiResponse)
    console.log()

}
}
```

I don't understand how to handle / access the data returned by a http post service in the component.
I see in the response preview of chrome debugger that it actually returns the data expected.

Preview of google chrome debugger:

```
{Error: false, ErrorMessage: null, Data: {SessionId: "dgm6k7l1u763n26578k22rjot1",…}}
Data
:
{SessionId: "dgm6k7l1u763n26578k22rjot1",…}
Error
:
false
ErrorMessage
:
null
```

Can anybody guide me?

Thanks....

**Update**

I have now written the following code:

```
login(): void {
        console.log(this.usercredentials)
 this.apiResponse = apiResponse; console.log(this.apiResponse);})
    this.loginService.login(this.usercredentials).then(apiResponse => { this.apiResponse = apiResponse;  
        if (!this.apiResponse.Error) {
            console.log("user logged in")
        } else {
            console.log(this.apiResponse.ErrorMessage)
        }
    })
}
```

And this seems to work.
Should error handling be done in the service or in the component?

Comment: You are doing `console.log(this.apiResponse)` outside the promise, if you move your console.log into the promise like this: `this.loginService.login(this.usercredentials).then(apiResponse => { this.apiResponse = apiResponse; console.log(this.apiResponse);})` You will access the data

Comment: What's the `ApiResponse` hold? Just the data? or the error also?

Comment: @FabioAntunes Thank you, indeed that works.
So I would be able to assign it to a class inside the component.
Is this design correct??
The idea is to publish an event where different components would listen too.

Comment: @Maniac_1979 you are already assigning that data into a property on the class by doing this `this.apiResponse = apiResponse`

Comment: @FabioAntunes, please see my update

Comment: @Maniac_1979 there's no right or wrong, it really depends on your app, both options are valid

Comment: @FabioAntunes your comment should be made into an answer.